# Как в gunicorn config использовать --reload

Tags: python, django, gunicorn

http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/19.0/settings.html#reload
Пользуюсь хостингов digital ocean, поставил py+ django. Всё стало и всё отлично, но gunicorn кеширует, а это dev server. Попытался в конфиге прописать --reload=true(false) не сработало. Вот конфиг целиком.

```
description "Gunicorn daemon for Django project"

start on (local-filesystems and net-device-up IFACE=eth0)
stop on runlevel [!12345]

# If the process quits unexpectadly trigger a respawn
respawn

setuid django
setgid django
chdir /home/django

exec gunicorn \
    --name=django_project \
    --pythonpath=django_project \
    --workers=3 \
    --bind=127.0.0.1:9000 \
    --config /etc/gunicorn.d/gunicorn.py \
    django_project.wsgi:application
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где Я ошибся?

мой gunicorn.py:

```
from multiprocessing import cpu_count
from os import environ


def max_workers():
    return cpu_count() * 2 + 1

max_requests = 1000
worker_class = 'gevent'
workers = max_workers()
```

Comment: `gunicorn.py` приложите свой

Comment: @dizballanze добавил, в вопросе.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вся проблема была в версии, надо было обновить gunicorn.
Сделал это так: `pip install -U gunicorn`

Answer (score 0):

У меня на `--reload=true` вообще не запускается. При просто `--reload` как положено перезапускается при изменениях .py-файлов.

Comment: не помогло, увы(